# Проблемы с postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

После выполнения этой команды
`$ sudo apt-get install postgrespro-std-10`
возвращается следующее сообщение:

```
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Невозможно найти пакет postgrespro-std-10
```

В книге написано, что после выполнения этой команды PostgreSQL будет установлена и проверить это можно командой `$ sudo -u postgres psql -c 'select now()'`.
После ее ввода мне возвращается текущее время.

Но после команды `$ sudo service postgrespro-std-10 start` возвращается сообщение `Failed to start postgrespro-std-10.service: Unit postgrespro-std-10.service not found.`

Почему так и как это исправить?

Comment: это вы сделали - "Подключите репозиторий пакетов, предназначенный для вашей операционной системы. Конкретные адреса репозиториев и команды для их подключения в поддерживаемых дистрибутивах Linux вы можете найти на Странице загрузки для соответствующей версии Postgres Pro."?

Comment: @nörbörnën,  `$ sudo apt-get install lsb-release` 


`$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://repo.postgrespro.ru/pgpro-10/debian $(lsb_release -cs) main" >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgrespro.list'`
`
`$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://repo.postgrespro.ru/pgpro-10/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgrespro.list'`
`$ sudo apt-get update`
Сделал вот это.

Comment: выглядит почти норм. а apt-key?

Comment: Про это ничего не писали.

Comment: попробуй от sudo `wget -O - http://repo.postgrespro.ru/keys/GPG-KEY-POSTGRESPRO | apt-key add -` и `sudo apt-get update` и снова попытка установить

Comment: Отдал эти команды и все успешно, но при выполнении `$ sudo apt-get install postgrespro-std-10` также, возвращает указанную выше ошибку.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115171/discussion-between-norbornen-and-borrya).

Comment: К сожалению у меня недостаточно репутации, разберусь тогда сам.